# not able to create table in kudu using impala-shell

Tags: impala, apache-kudu

I was doing R&D on hadoop, hive, impala, and kudu. Installed HADOOP, HIVE, IMPALA, and KUDU servers.

I have configured --kudu_master_hosts=: in /etc/default -> impala file. i.e like below:

```
IMPALA_SERVER_ARGS=" \
    -log_dir=${IMPALA_LOG_DIR} \
    -catalog_service_host=${IMPALA_CATALOG_SERVICE_HOST} \
    -state_store_port=${IMPALA_STATE_STORE_PORT} \
    -use_statestore \
    -state_store_host=${IMPALA_STATE_STORE_HOST} \
    -be_port=${IMPALA_BACKEND_PORT}\
    --kudu_master_hosts=<HOST_NAME>:<PORT>"
```

==============
Aftert that re-started the servers.
Then using Kudu JAVA client, i was able to create table in kudu and able to insert some records.

Then mapped the same table in impala by doing this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_mapping_table
STORED AS KUDU
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'kudu.table_name' = 'testT1'
);
```

successfully able to access the kudu table in impala and able to see all the records.
Now i was trying to create a table in KUDU using impala-shell.

```
[<HOST_NAME>:21000] > CREATE TABLE my_first_table
                               > (
                               >   id BIGINT,
                               >   name STRING,
                               >   PRIMARY KEY(id)
                               > )
                               > STORED AS KUDU;
```

But this is giving a error i.e :

```
ERROR: ImpalaRuntimeException: Error creating Kudu table 'impala::default.my_first_table'
CAUSED BY: NonRecoverableException: Not enough live tablet servers to create a table with the requested replication factor 3. 1 tablet servers are alive.
```

Can any one explain me what is happening or what is the solution for this error.

Read through KUDU documentation but not getting any ideas.

Regards,
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

This query will help to create table i.e

```
CREATE TABLE emp
(
  uname STRING,
  age INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(uname)
)
STORED AS KUDU
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'kudu.num_tablet_replicas' = '1'
);
```

This query will work only if, --kudu_master_hosts=: is set in /etc/default impala file.
Else u have to give kudu_master_hosts in table properties. i.e

```
TBLPROPERTIES (
      'kudu.num_tablet_replicas' = '1',
       --kudu_master_hosts=<HOST_NAME>:<PORT>
    );
```

Comment: Also you can verify in KUDU web page under Tables tab.i.e http://<HOST>:8051/tables